# Bolt CMS - automatic relations

Tags: symfony, bolt-cms

I'm new to Bolt CMS, but it looks good so far. My goal for now is to create rating for articles. For that, I created `ratings` content type, and there I placed `article_id`, `user_id` and `rating` fields. Now how can I set those fields to create relations between themselves?

Since Bolt is biult on Symfony, I'd expect it to use Doctrine and its tools.

My current contenttype for `ratings` is very poor:

```
ratings:
    name: Ratings
    slug: ratings
    singular_name: Rating
    singular_slug: rating
    fields:
        article_id:
            type: integer
        user_id:
            type: integer
        rating:
            type: integer
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly should the rating do? Do visitors have to be able to rate articles? In that case you might look at the rateit extension http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/5d137130-4ab8-4e75-9d58-43f3f99c5a5a

Comment: It's actually a little more complex - I plan to have something like "best articles" with highest rated ones etc. I would prefer to do this _my way_ that to rely on plugins.

Comment: You can use relations in bolt contenttypes, see https://docs.bolt.cm/relationships .. so you might have a content type articles and a content type ratings, where a rating is related to an article but the interface will get very convoluted

Comment: I have both `article` and `rating` contenttype, but I don't know how to join them the way I want. I need automatic binding, not something picked from the CMS' panel by hand.

Comment: you could add a choice field called `rating` with 1-5 stars to your content type, and then use `{% setcontent topten = 'article' limit 10 orderby '-rating' %}`  to get the ten highest rated articles https://docs.bolt.cm/content-fetching

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, what you want is to have, ratings and articles relationship.
Here is the code for that. Articles has many Ratings.

```
ratings:
    name: Ratings
    singular_name: Rating
    fields:
        name:
            label: Name
            type: text
            group: General
        email:
            label: Email
            type: text
            group: General

articles:
    name: Articles
    singular_name: Article
    fields:
        name:
            label: Name
            type: text
            group: General
    relations:
        ratings:
            multiple: true
            label: "Choose ratings"
```

It´s important to understand that BOLT CMS is built on Shoulders of Symphony and Silex. But for getting content, you don´t have to use Doctrine Query. I recommend taking a look at the Backend folder that has Records.php if you are on BOLT 3.* or Backend.php if you are on older versions. Check the editContent action. And if you want on the Frontend.php it's easy to follow the code.

Hope this helps !!!